# Creating a profile for updating multiple membership records

Tags: civimember, profile, batches, multiple-records

I have read how to do a batch update of multiple membership records. This involves having already created a profile. I have tried creating a membership profile but when i try to do the update multiple records after my advanced search it says i need a profile. My profile record must be wrong.

Can anyone point me to a idiots guide to creating profiles that will show me how to create for a batch update.

thanks
Dave

Answer (score 1):

If you use Advanced Search, you're searching for contacts, not memberships — and you can't use a memberships profile to update contacts.

But if you use Memberships - Find Membership to search for memberships, you should be able to select your memberships profile to update them.

Comment: You can also use Adv Search but in top left corner set it to 'Show Memberships'